# PHP: Does die() must die?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it considered bad practice to let die() live in a production enviroment? Just happened to read this article http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/or-die-must-die where the author fies upon people who use such a thing in a production enviroment. So shouldn't I code this way:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$connection){
    die ("Could not connect to the database.");
}
```

How do you code?

Comment: It is bad practice to show end users your database errors - those should be logged some how, and a generic error shown to you users.

Comment: By the way, the best topic-title ever!

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130105/should-you-always-end-mysql-queries-with-or-die/2130127#2130127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *die* everytime you make a mistake, do you. Why should your application do?

the correct way is to intercept errors and process them in a context-dependent fashion, for example

```
try {
    application goes here

    $conn = mysql_connect(...)
    if(!$conn)
        throw ....
    ....
} catch(Exception $err) {
     if(PRODUCTION) {
        log error
        say something nice
     }
     if(DEBUG) {
         var_dump($err);
     }
}
```

Comment: A subjective question. Why do you prefer to raise and catch an exception instead of handling in the `if(!$conn)` condition?

Comment: Enrico, because exceptions are better suited to breaking out of the standard flow of the program and passing control to error handling code. It is also a more robust way to 'crash early': if instead you rely on if/else conditions everywhere, you have to remember every time to call the correct functions to terminate execution.

Answer (score 3):

`die()` is a very rough statement... Useful (quite) in developer stage, i found it *wrong* in production stage.

You should analyze, monitor and log fatal errors, and displaying adequate messages like "It's impossible to connect to the server, please try in few minutes or write to admin@yourhost.com to notify the problem"!

Answer (score 1):

Well in a productive enivornment, you should never expose any errors/information about the system to the outside world.

Important is, to log all errors. If you are talking about a website, I would send an `HTTP status 500` as response.